# MySQL Workbench on MySQL 5.6.19

Tags: 14.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to install MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 after installing Mysql 5.6 library, but get the following: error:

**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installed. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mysql-workbench:

- Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
- Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
- Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
- Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
- Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be installed

---

According to this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72729), there has been an error before but should being solved with the MySQL-Workbench 6.1.7 +

> Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 release, and here's the change-log entry
>
> On Ubuntu 14, the dependency check was updated to allow any of
> mysql-client, mysql-client-5.6 or mysql-community-client client libraries.
> Previously, the dependency check could fail.

---

I have tried to install the workbench vie Software-Center and also tried the version from [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

if i grep mysql-client i get the following output

```
ii  mysql-client-5.6        5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64   MySQL database client binaries

ii  mysql-client-core-5.6   5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1   amd64   MySQL database core client binaries
```

For me it seems that the bug is not solved, or that there is maybe a problem with the mysql version 5.6.**19** !?

Or could it be that another package dependency occurs this problem?

Any suggestion or workaround to get the workbench running on mysql 5.6.19 would be great!

---

### UPDATE

I couldn't figure out why the installation of MySQL Workbench 6.1.7 does not work with mysql 5.6.19 , but with the latest Workbench **Development Release [Version 6.2.2 rc]** everything works fine.

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I just installed the latest development release and that version works for me. Also workbench 6.* is now officially released and should work. I just did a regular update without any problems. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Install gcc and python in your machine and try again

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc python2.7
```